# Django Rest Framework custom response for validation failure

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

### Background

I am new to Django and the rest framework, and I am trying to use the Django Rest Framework to build an API Demo of Register and Login for mobile app.

### I want

I am using `APIView` and the `ModelSerializer`, and the arguments and contraints for registion are

```
email <required, unique>,
username <required, unique>,
password <required, unique>,
```

and here, my requirements focus on the exception, I want to get a custom error code to indicate that what validations(required or unique) has failed.

### For example

when I send the arguments:

```
username="", (leaves it blank)
password=123, 
email="xxx@yyy.com"
```

this will lead to the `required` validation failure, and the JSON response returns something like

```
"username": [
    "This field may not be blank."
]
```

but, I want the JSON response to be something like

```
{
    error_code: 1,
    msg: "blah blah blah"
}
```

in this way, mobile app can do whatever it wants according to the error_code.

### Problems

I have found that, inside the framework's validation implementation, validation failures(all fields validation failures) have been transformed to plain texts and packed in an array, I can not get the specific exception(such as the username required exception), and I can not generate the error_code in the response.

So, is there any way to catch the specific exception?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for including those error codes in the response? Why clients can't use http error codes?

Comment: @mikedanylov http error code will help, but I want the error to be more specific, such as `required` validation failure or `unique` validation failure. The default http error code 400 seems just tell me some validation failure, which is not specific enough

Comment: Probably then you would need to write custom validations for all fields. It can be done by overriding validate method of serializer for each field. For example, for password you would need to override method `validate_password` and there you can format field error object anyway you like.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [extra_kwargs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)

## code

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = User
    extra_kwargs = {"username": {"error_messages": {"required": "Give yourself a username"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there anything else I should do? It did not work after I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

in you serializer's `to_internal_value`, you can catch ValidatonErrors and modify them.

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return super().to_internal_value(data)
        except serializers.ValidationError as err:
            # do something with the error messages
            # reraise with the modified ValidationError
            raise err
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

Comment: thanks, but I found that clue to identify required failure or unique failure are the plain text. Is there something like a flag can tell me the required failure or unique failure?

Comment: The plain text is contained in the `ValidationError.detail` property which should either be a dictionary or a list. You can read the source code to figure out exactly how to access the data you want. https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/exceptions.py

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround.

```
username = serializers.CharField(
    validators=[
        UniqueValidator(
            queryset=Account.objects.all(),
            message=convert_dictionary_to_json_string({
                'error_code': ErrorCode.parameter.value,
                'msg': 'username exists',
            }),
        ),
    ],
    # ...other validators
)
```

Since we can only pass a message which is string type, in a validator, we can:

1. build a dictionary which containes the error message we need
2. convert this dictionary to JSON string
3. just pass the JSON string to the `message` field

After that, in the `view` code, if validation fails:

1. we convert the error message, which is JSON string, in the `serializer.errors`, to the dictionary
2. pack it up to the response